# Mysql query suggestion for Mysql 5.5

Tags: mysql

I have the following query that run lovely in mysql 5.6, but in 5.5 it take 10 secs to execute, i know there is a perfomance issue with the NOT IN clause in older mysql version but i dont see another way to handle it in old mysql versions, i would really appreciate any suggestion:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT C.chapter, 
J.name 
FROM chart as C 
INNER JOIN resume as J ON J.serie_id = C.serie_id 
WHERE chapter NOT IN 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT chapter FROM chart WHERE recorded = '0000-00-00'
) 
AND 
(
  C.chapter NOT IN 
  (
     SELECT chapter FROM chart_2
  )
) 
ORDER BY chapter DESC
```

Bassicly what it does is to select unique chapters from a chart table and the name from the joined table, then it select again from chart table unique chapters that have a date as 0000-00-00 what means that have not been yet recorded and do a match to exclude those that are in the first subquery using the NOT IT. I use the distinct because in the chart table the chapter can be repeated several times, and i just want to select those chapters that are recorded as a single result (like grouping them). Finally it check that the chapter dont exists on the chart_2 table. It work ok on mysql 5.6 but in 5.5 it just take to long. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you already try an EXPLAIN on this query?

Comment: yes use explain and see how it looks.

Comment: ok on my way, ill report back

Comment: Ok i see type ALL key NULL and possible key NULL thats not good

Comment: Yes thats not good. Make sure u have indexes on joining keys and more over add an index on recorded for chapter table.

Comment: Im not so used to add indexes, but i just test it adding index to the chapter column in chart table and in the ID column in the joined table and to the chapter column on the chart_2 table and the query time jumped from 9 sec to 0.4 secs, pretty good. I can add indexes to the important columns just like that?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly try it as joins.

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT C.chapter, 
J.name 
FROM chart as C 
INNER JOIN resume as J ON J.serie_id = C.serie_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN chart C1 ON C.chapter = C1.chapter AND C1.recorded = '0000-00-00'
LEFT OUTER JOIN chart_2 C2 ON C.chapter = C2.chapter 
WHERE C1.chapter IS NULL
AND C2.chapter IS NULL
ORDER BY C.chapter DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I've had so many poor performing queries like this one that I've found it better to  get a list of values for a separate query for an in clause rather than using a subquery.

So get a set of results from SELECT DISTINCT chapter FROM chart WHERE recorded = '0000-00-00'
and SELECT chapter FROM chart_2, combine them then add them to your query.